# Ignore Gradle Build Failure and continue build script?

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Managing Android's dependencies with Gradle is done in a weird way. They have to be downloaded differently into a local repo. This is a pain when setting up CI build as there are multiple nodes this could run on. As such I'm using the [sdk-manager-plugin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin) to have the Android dependencies downloaded at build time. There seems to be [an old bug](https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin/issues/10) that I'm experiencing with the sdk-manager-plugin though in that it will download the dependencies at build time, but they won't be available on that command.

The next time the command is run everything works fine (as everything is already downloaded), but I need to find a way to ignore the build failure of the first gradle command so that everything is downloaded and good to go for the second. I realize this is hacky, but I'm done messing with this.

Ideally something like this would work:

```
./gradlew clean --ignoreBuildFailures
./gradlew distributeCIBuild
```

The closest thing I could find in the Gradle documentation is --quite but that doesn't look like it'd work.

Any creative solutions welcome.

Comment: What about `--continue`?

Comment: I can't find any documentation on `--continue`.

Comment: Try running `./gradlew --help` or looking at [1]. The description is "Continues task execution after a task failure". [1]: https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html

Comment: In the example I post above with the fake `--ignoreBuildFailures`, do you think it'd work if I replace that with `--continue`? It sounds like it'd still fail the build after the clean was run. It just saves it till the end.

Comment: That appears to have worked (although it's difficult to reproduce sometimes). Would you mind creating an answer, and I'll mark it correct in a day or so?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The flag to use is `--continue`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:continue_build_on_failure):

> Continues task execution after a task failure.

Comment: thanks for the very very valuable answer. I was able to solve a client deployment issue because of this. :)

Comment: @UtkarshMankad you cannot be serious :o

Comment: Our way of enabling "Warnings as Errors" but keeping things easy for "trying things out".

Comment: in which file do i need to add this line

Answer (score 5):

add this in the build.gradle file :

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.failOnError(false)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ignoreExitValue`

```
task ktlint(type: JavaExec, group: "verification") {
    description = "Check Kotlin code style."
    ignoreExitValue = true
}
```