# Silently handle Gradle task failure

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, sonar-runner

I have a project which should run a specific Gradle task (`sonarqube` task) only if a condition is met after `build` task is executed. This task can fail as it communicates with a remote server which is sometimes not available. If the server is unavailable, I'd like to silently handle the error an print some message to console instead of failing the whole build.

Currently I am able to do so with the following configuration:

```java
build.doLast {
    if ('desired.value' == System.properties['some.prop']) {
        try {
            tasks.sonarqube.execute()
        } catch(e) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However using this method I get deprecation messages. After reading up a bit I supposedly should not be using `execute`, so instead I came up with this:

```java
if ('desired.value' == System.properties['some.property']) {
    build.finalizedBy sonarqube
}
```

However in this case, if `sonarqube` task fails my whole build will fail as well. How could I handle `sonarqube` task failures in such case?

I am using Gradle `4.5.1`.

**Edit**

The builds are ran using the following command:

```
./gradlew build
```

Modifying it like the following will cause Gradle to ignore not only `sonarqube` failures, but also `build` failures which is not what I want:

```
./gradlew build --continue
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore Gradle Build Failure and continue build script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998372/ignore-gradle-build-failure-and-continue-build-script)

Comment: @lu.koerfer I'm running my builds using the following command `./gradlew build`. Adding `--continue` will ignore `build` task failures and not only `sonarqube` failures.

Comment: This discussion recommends to not run sonarqube task with all other tasks: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-ignore-failed-server-sonarqube-uploads-in-gradle/12640. That gradle forum is also a good place for you to ask about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, once a Gradle task fails it's not possible to elegantly recover from that. Therefore you need to avoid that happening.

I can think of three ways to do that:

1. Find a way of executing the code you want to execute directly without it being wrapped by a Gradle task (eg via a command line or Java process). Then execute that code inside of a `try-catch` block in the normal fashion.
2. Activate an option in the `sonarqube` task which means that task does not fail when there is a problem but reports back to a parent task in another way (eg by setting a property on the `Task` object), which can in turn deal with the problem. (Having looked quickly it does not appear any such option exists, but you could request it or write a pull request.)
3. Run another task before the `sonarqube` task to check if the remote server is available first (and/or other potential failure conditions); then you can deal with the server not being available gracefully, including not running the `sonarqube` task.

The last option could work as follows by executing a new `sonarqubeWrapper` task:

```
tasks.register("sonarqubeWrapper") {
   doFirst {
      if (isServerAvailable()) {
         // Deal with the server not being available
         throw new StopExecutionException()
      }
   }
   doLast('sonarqube')
}

def isServerAvailable() {
   // Determine if server available
}
```